# Mapstruct "ignore" sets the value of target

Tags: java, mapstruct

do I something wrong or si this bug in Mapstruct? I am having this mapper definition:

```java
@Mapping(target = "isEnabled", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "isCredentialsNonExpired", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "isAccountNonLocked", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "isAccountNonExpired", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "grantedAuthorities", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "userName", source = "email")
    UserCredentials toUserCredentials(User user);
```

and MapStruct generates this implementation:

```java
@Component
public class UserCredentialsMapperImpl implements UserCredentialsMapper {

    @Override
    public UserCredentials toUserCredentials(User user) {
        if ( user == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String userName = null;
        String password = null;

        userName = user.getEmail();
        password = user.getPassword();

        boolean isEnabled = false;
        boolean isCredentialsNonExpired = false;
        boolean isAccountNonLocked = false;
        boolean isAccountNonExpired = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = null;

        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials( grantedAuthorities, password, userName, isAccountNonExpired, isAccountNonLocked, isCredentialsNonExpired, isEnabled );

        return userCredentials;
    }
}
```

as you can see even though I have set isEnabled to ignore it is setting it to false instead of ignoring it...

**EDITED**:

After comments from Federico klez Culloca I realized, that MapStruct is doing everything right. The problem was in my logic. I wanted to have default values for those ignored fields, but because my class was immutable and I had all arg constructor, MapStruct had to insert some value into those fields and that is why it inserted there false value. I was able to solve this problem using Builder pattern, now MapStruct sets only the correct fields and default values are used for the rest. Thanks all for help.

```java
@Override
    public UserCredentials toUserCredentials(User user) {
        if ( user == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserCredentialsBuilder userCredentials = UserCredentials.builder();

        userCredentials.userName( user.getEmail() );
        userCredentials.password( user.getPassword() );

        return userCredentials.build();
    }
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead, considering that `UserCredential`'s constructor still expect a `boolean` (and that its default value would be `false` anyway) there?

Comment: Yep, my bad. Make sense now when I thing about it ...

Comment: I will use builder in the target class, sorry this was really basic mistake from my side :)

Comment: Even if you use a builder pattern, that will still set the class member to `false` by default. If you want `null`, make it a `Boolean` instead.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to have default value as true and if there will be mapping for this field (isActive) from User to UserCredentials in the future it would set it's value, I would just delete the "ignore" annotation.

Comment: I will write it first and add it here.

Comment: instead of `ignore = true` you can use `constant = "true"` to set the default values to true.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have solved my problem with the builder pattern, this way I have the default values in the class not in the mapper it self.